# How to make a menu like in Dropbox app?

Tags: android, android-layout

i want to make menu in my android app which looks like the one in the dropbox-app.

I guess I have to work with fragments, what I already do, but i cant find any examples on how to implement this. Maybe someone can give me any hints how to make this menu like:

Here you can find an example image of the dropbox app:

[image: Image Screenshot]

You can open it with a single click. I want to use it on a gridview.
Maybe I just do not know the right name of such a menu to search for.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Its called a "QuickAction" dialog. See this link: http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=347

Answer (score 0):

Action bar is supported in 3.1 API's but you can use context menu for this
Or This can also be done using "sliding drawer "